# Listing certain items within a folder within the current directory

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a a script editor for a game that runs on a certain API. I have a `listbox` that I want to list all the `.txt` and `.lua` files in the scripts folder within the current application directory. Then by highlighting the list box item and clicking my open button below it, I want it to get the data out of those files and output it in my `textbox`. I tried

```
var folder = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
var txtFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.txt");
var luaFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.lua");

listBox1.Items.AddRange(txtFiles);
listBox1.Items.AddRange(luaFiles);
```

and it only got the `.txt`'s and `.lua`'s from the only application directory and not the child of it. Although it did display the files inside of that folder, the names of the items were the entire directory for them and I only want it to be the name of the files.

Comment: You might want to process the names with [`Path.GetFileName(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=net-5.0#System_IO_Path_GetFileName_System_String_).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
. . .  . . . . .  . . . 
string[] luaFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.lua", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f)).ToArray();
listBox1.DataSource = luaFiles;
```

Better yet....

```
public class ListBoxItem
{
    public string FileName {get;set;}
    public string FilePath {get;set;}
}
. . . . . .  .
ListBoxItem[] luaFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.lua", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Select(f => new ListBoxItem()
                    {
                        FileName = Path.GetFileName(f),
                        FilePath = f
                    }).ToArray();
listBox1.ValueMember = "FilePath";
listBox1.DisplayMember = "FileName";
listBox1.DataSource = luaFiles;

// THEN you Usage becomes way more flexible
.......
if (listBox1.SelectedIndex > -1)
    txtFilePath.Text = ((ListBoxItem)listBox1.SelectedItem).FilePath;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search all directories you can add `SearchOption.AllDirectories`

like:

```
var txtFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Then if you want to get the only filename, you can use `Path.GetFileName()`.

like:

```
foreach(var file in txtFiles)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
}
```